# How to share 2 apples equally

Tags: situation

This is trending on Twitter now, but it's just too delicious to not post. Downvote if you must!

The riddle is:

> Only 6% of people can handle this puzzle: These three want to share two apples equally, how can you handle this by using only one stroke of the knife?

[image: sharing apples]

Hint (which was also included with the original question):

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer indicated by the hint is

> to kill one of the children.

Since this is not a practical solution to the problem in real life - this will get you in some amount of trouble most places - the actual solution is to

> place them on top of each other, and cut one third off of both apples. This gives you two two-thirds and two thirds, so everyone gets two thirds.